# ASP.NET not redirecting to defaultURL automatically after ending session

Tags: asp.net, session, forms-authentication, session-cookies, inproc

This seems to be a very trivial question but still I am not able to get it running. I am building an asp.net web application and I am using forms authentication here. The following steps I have followed.

1) In web.config this is the entry

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="StockTips.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"
                 slidingExpiration="true" />
        </authentication>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />
```

2) In default.aspx I have used custom authentication and after authentication passes I am redirecting to defaultUrl mentioned in web.config. The following is the code. This is working fine.

```
Session["test"] = "testing";
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
```

Login1 is Login control of asp.net.

3) In StockTips.aspx (which is defaulturl), on Logout linkbutton click event I am trying to abandon session so that it automatically redirects to loginurl (default.aspx). This is not happening. It is staying on the same page i.e. StockTips.aspx. The following is the code.

```
        protected void lnkLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = Session["test"].ToString();

            Session.Abandon();
            //Session.RemoveAll();
            //Session.Clear();
            //Response.Cookies.Remove("ASP.NET_SessionId"); 
            //Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty; 
            //Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "")); 

            //FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            string str1 = Session["test"].ToString();
        }
```

The value in Session["test"] also remains. I have tried the commented code above. I do not want to explicitly write Response.Redirect to loginurl as I am pretty sure once the session gets abondoned it automatically redirects to loginurl. But somehow it is not working.

I am not sure whether the following information will help but still thought of adding it. I have a master page in which both default.aspx and stocktips.aspx opens. LinkButton in inside stocktips.aspx and not on master page.

Please let me know if you need any further information from my side.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Samar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config

```
<forms name="WhateverYourAuthNameIs" 
   loginUrl="~/HomePage.aspx" 
   defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
   protection="All" path="/" 
   cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
```

Even Try Js Code also

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(function(){document.location.href='/Home.aspx';},30000);">
```

Hope It Helps you

Comment: In the "name" attribute of the "form" tag u hv written "WhateverYourAuthNameIs". By default it is ".ASPXAUTH". What should i enter instead of "WhateverYourAuthNameIs"?

Comment: What is your Authentication Mode is ? If you are using ASP.Net forms authentication then under the name attribute is "MyAuthCookie".

Comment: I think with your code session is getting ended but still on clicking any button which causes postback asp.net is not automatically redirecting to loginUrl. Am I expecting too much from ASP.NET? Is it that asp.net does not redirect to loginUrl after session expiry and that I have to do it myself?